How to overload functions to handle Any-arguments?
I have a function whose return type is sensitive to multiple arguments:
If a given predicate is strong enough to provide a type constraint,
the input values are similarly constrained (T | None -> T or T -> R where R <: T).
This is straightforward to type-hint if all types are known:
from typing import Any, Callable, Iterable, Iterator, TypeGuard, TypeVar, overload

T = TypeVar("T")
R = TypeVar("R")

@overload  # 1
def select(pred: None, values: Iterable[T | None]) -> Iterator[T]: ...
@overload  # 2
def select(pred: Callable[[T], TypeGuard[R]], values: Iterable[T]) -> Iterator[R]: ...
@overload  # 3
def select(pred: Callable[[T], Any], values: Iterable[T]) -> Iterator[T]: ...

However, there is a problem if the argument types are not known:
If the predicate is Any, one would expect the least typing constraint and thus the same output type as the input values.
Yet, available type checkers do not agree1 with this:
MyPy looses the type almost completely to the overly generic Iterator[Any] and PyRight matches the None special case and provides the overconstraint Iterator[int].
How do I correctly type-hint an overload in which Any can match special cases?
Notably, reordering is not sufficient.
If I order overloads as 2-3-1 then Any does not provide an R and type checkers cannot fall back to T.
If I order overloads as 3-2-1 then (T) -> Any shadows (T) -> TypeGuard[R] completely.

1 Given a prelude of
from typing import Any, reveal_type

iitr: list[int | None] = [0, 1, 2, None, 3]
any_pred: Any = lambda val: not val  # could be any unknown function

the type checkers I tested all fail in various ways when the unknown predicate is used:



case
expected
MyPy
Pyright




select(None, iitr)
Iterator[int]
Iterator[int]
Iterator[int]


select(bool, iitr)
Iterator[int | None]
Iterator[int | None]
Iterator[int | None]


select(any_pred, iitr)
Iterator[int | None]
Iterator[Any]
Iterator[int]




If you figure this out, consider contributing to typeshed (link to upstream definition): your select has the same behavior as filter, and filter suffers from the same problem!

@STerliakov Yes, that’s no coincidence: it’s an MRE for an async filter function.

I imagine there's some bug in the mypy checker. Interestingly adding in a reveal_type call: assert_type(select(any_pred, reveal_type(iitr)), Iterator[int | None]) causes the error to change to Expression is of type "Iterator[int]", not "Iterator[int | None]"  instead of Iterator[Any]

For Pyright, you can make use of Never to match a Any input.
from typing import Any, Callable, Iterable, Iterator, Never, TypeGuard, TypeVar, overload

T = TypeVar("T")
R = TypeVar("R")

@overload  # Added
def select(pred: Never, values: Iterable[T]) -> Iterator[T]: ...
@overload  # 1
def select(pred: None, values: Iterable[T | None]) -> Iterator[T]: ...
@overload  # 2
def select(pred: Callable[[T], TypeGuard[R]], values: Iterable[T]) -> Iterator[R]: ...
@overload  # 3
def select(pred: Callable[[T], Any], values: Iterable[T]) -> Iterator[T]: ...

For Mypy, I haven't thought of a solution yet, because there seems no way to indicate that R is a subtype of T, and Mypy adds all possible result types which would be unconstrained and therefore be Any.
